# How to identify the exact brand of the embedded smart card reader of my laptop

Tags: smartcard

I have a HP EliteBook 2170p and I am trying to use the embedded smart card reader.

First I installed all necessary packages `pcscd`, `opensc`, ...

Then I tested the command `pcsc_scan` and I get the message "unresponsive card":

```
jose@EliteX:~$ pcsc_scan 
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.5.2 (c) 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Alcor Micro AU9560 00 00
Thu Apr 12 21:08:11 2018
 Reader 0: Alcor Micro AU9560 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
```

I read in forums that it could be a damaged card but I also read that it is a problem of the driver. So I thought that maybe I don't have an Alcor Micro device.

To double check this I did:

```
jose@EliteX:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b2ef Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2717:ff48  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also I executed `lspci`:

```
jose@EliteX:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
02:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

...and I don't see Alcor Micro anywhere. :(  There is an SD controller but that is a different reader that the laptop has.

Could you please help me out to identify the exact hardware vendor of the reader?

I also tried to check in the HP website without luck.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? I fear the suggestions in my answer might not have been adequate. Did they help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [the manual for your laptop](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03387961) does not appear to provide much information about the smart card reader. It occurred to me that your reader might be using [the AU9540 controller](http://www.alcormicro.com/en_content/c_product/product_01b.php?CategoryID=4&IndexID=4), but it looks like that *might* just be used for external USB smart card readers.

If `lspci` and `lsusb` don't find a device, or don't give enough information about it, then I recommend you use `lshw`. Although you can run it as a non-root user, I recommend running it as root, with `sudo lshw`, for best results.

If you're willing to look through what may be a lot of output, you can just start with this, which I think is the most likely way to find information about it, of all the easy ways:

```
sudo lshw
```

It occurred to me that you *might* find your card reader listed in the storage or disk classes -- though that might just show the SD controller but not the smart card reader. This will produce significantly less output, though:

```
sudo lshw -C disk,storage
```

You may also find brand and related information about devices that your system attempted to use (whether or not it succeeded) in your `dmesg`. Just running `dmesg` will usually produce an enormous amount of output, but you can filter it with `grep`:

```
dmesg | grep -Fi alcor
```

The `-F` option makes `grep` treat your search pattern as a "fixed string" rather than a regular expression (and is, in this case, optional). The `-i` option makes it match case-insensitively. That displays lines from `dmesg` that contain `alcor`, `Alcor`, `ALCOR`, and so forth.

Comment: No luck,  dmesg + grep gave no results. 
I could not find any relevant info in the lshw output either. Do you know which capacity should I look for in the lshw output?

Answer (score 0):

here the output of lshw, I dont see anything relevant.. :/

```
sudo lshw elitex                      
    descripción: Notebook
    producto: HP EliteBook 2170p (C3C59ES#ABU)
    fabricante: Hewlett-Packard
    versión: A1029D1102
    serie: 2CE2520V1H
    anchura: 64 bits
    capacidades: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuración: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=ELI sku=C3C59ES#ABU uuid=82933787-934E-E211-B13E-4889B3008084   *-core
       descripción: Placa base
       producto: 1815
       fabricante: Hewlett-Packard
       id físico: 0
       versión: KBC Version 63.1C
       serie: PDARR1B2E3S2AO
     *-firmware
          descripción: BIOS
          fabricante: Hewlett-Packard
          id físico: e
          versión: 68IMT Ver. F.63
          date: 05/04/2016
          tamaño: 64KiB
          capacidad: 5056KiB
          capacidades: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          descripción: CPU
          producto: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3427U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          fabricante: Intel Corp.
          id físico: 0
          información del bus: cpu@0
          versión: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3427U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          serie: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          ranura: U3E1
          tamaño: 2769MHz
          capacidad: 4GHz
          anchura: 64 bits
          reloj: 100MHz
          capacidades: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti retpoline spec_ctrl tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuración: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             descripción: L1 caché
             id físico: 2
             ranura: Unknown
             tamaño: 32KiB
             capacidad: 32KiB
             capacidades: internal write-through instruction
             configuración: level=1
        *-cache:1
             descripción: L2 caché
             id físico: 3
             ranura: Unknown
             tamaño: 256KiB
             capacidad: 256KiB
             capacidades: internal write-through unified
             configuración: level=2
        *-cache:2
             descripción: L3 caché
             id físico: 4
             ranura: Unknown
             tamaño: 3MiB
             capacidad: 3MiB
             capacidades: internal write-back unified
             configuración: level=3
     *-cache
          descripción: L1 caché
          id físico: 1
          ranura: Unknown
          tamaño: 32KiB
          capacidad: 32KiB
          capacidades: internal write-through data
          configuración: level=1
     *-memory
          descripción: Memoria de sistema
          id físico: 5
          ranura: Placa de sistema o placa base
          tamaño: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             descripción: SODIMM DDR3 Síncrono 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             producto: 8KTF25664HZ-1G6M1
             fabricante: Micron
             id físico: 0
             serie: 38269327
             ranura: Bottom-Slot 1(top)
             tamaño: 2GiB
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             descripción: SODIMM DDR3 Síncrono 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             producto: 8KTF25664HZ-1G6M1
             fabricante: Micron
             id físico: 1
             serie: 36524278
             ranura: Bottom-Slot 2(under)
             tamaño: 2GiB
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          descripción: Host bridge
          producto: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          fabricante: Intel Corporation
          id físico: 100
          información del bus: pci@0000:00:00.0
          versión: 09
          anchura: 32 bits
          reloj: 33MHz
          configuración: driver=ivb_uncore
          recursos: irq:0
        *-display
             descripción: VGA compatible controller
             producto: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
             versión: 09
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
             recursos: irq:32 memoria:d0000000-d03fffff memoria:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memoria:c0000-dffff
        *-usb:0
             descripción: USB controller
             producto: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 14
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:14.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             recursos: irq:29 memoria:d0720000-d072ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                producto: xHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.13.0-39-generic xhci-hcd
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: usb@3
                nombre lógico: usb3
                versión: 4.13
                capacidades: usb-2.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   descripción: Ratón
                   producto: Logitech USB Optical Mouse
                   fabricante: Logitech
                   id físico: 2
                   información del bus: usb@3:2
                   versión: 43.00
                   capacidades: usb-2.00
                   configuración: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=1Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                producto: xHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.13.0-39-generic xhci-hcd
                id físico: 1
                información del bus: usb@4
                nombre lógico: usb4
                versión: 4.13
                capacidades: usb-3.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication:0
             descripción: Communication controller
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 16
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:16.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=mei_me latency=0
             recursos: irq:33 memoria:d0734000-d073400f
        *-communication:1
             descripción: Serial controller
             producto: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 16.3
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:16.3
             versión: 04
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 66MHz
             capacidades: pm msi 16550 bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=serial latency=0
             recursos: irq:17 ioport:2090(size=8) memoria:d073b000-d073bfff
        *-network
             descripción: Ethernet interface
             producto: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 19
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
             nombre lógico: enp0s25
             versión: 04
             serie: 10:1f:74:77:e3:0b
             capacidad: 1Gbit/s
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.15-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             recursos: irq:30 memoria:d0700000-d071ffff memoria:d073a000-d073afff ioport:2060(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             descripción: USB controller
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1a
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             recursos: irq:16 memoria:d0739000-d07393ff
           *-usbhost
                producto: EHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.13.0-39-generic ehci_hcd
                id físico: 1
                información del bus: usb@1
                nombre lógico: usb1
                versión: 4.13
                capacidades: usb-2.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   descripción: USB hub
                   producto: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   fabricante: Intel Corp.
                   id físico: 1
                   información del bus: usb@1:1
                   versión: 0.00
                   capacidades: usb-2.00
                   configuración: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0 NO RECLAMADO
                      descripción: Dispositivo USB genérico
                      producto: VFS491
                      fabricante: Validity Sensors, Inc.
                      id físico: 1
                      información del bus: usb@1:1.1
                      versión: 1.04
                      serie: 00209e22ed8d
                      capacidades: usb-1.10
                      configuración: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      descripción: Vídeo
                      producto: HP HD Webcam [Fixed]
                      fabricante: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
                      id físico: 3
                      información del bus: usb@1:1.3
                      versión: 51.72
                      serie: SN0001
                      capacidades: usb-2.00
                      configuración: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             descripción: Audio device
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1b
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 64 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             recursos: irq:34 memoria:d0730000-d0733fff
        *-pci:0
             descripción: PCI bridge
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1c
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             versión: c4
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:26 memoria:d0600000-d06fffff
        *-pci:1
             descripción: PCI bridge
             producto: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1c.2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             versión: c4
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:27 memoria:d0500000-d05fffff
           *-generic:0
                descripción: System peripheral
                producto: SD/MMC Host Controller
                fabricante: JMicron Technology Corp.
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
                versión: 30
                anchura: 32 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
                configuración: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                recursos: irq:18 memoria:d0503000-d05030ff memoria:d0510000-d051ffff
           *-generic:1 NO RECLAMADO
                descripción: SD Host controller
                producto: Standard SD Host Controller
                fabricante: JMicron Technology Corp.
                id físico: 0.2
                información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.2
                versión: 30
                anchura: 32 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuración: latency=0
                recursos: memoria:d0502000-d05020ff
        *-pci:2
             descripción: PCI bridge
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1c.3
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             versión: c4
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:28 memoria:d0400000-d04fffff
           *-network
                descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
                producto: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
                fabricante: Intel Corporation
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
                nombre lógico: wlo1
                versión: 34
                serie: 84:3a:4b:12:f5:e8
                anchura: 64 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-39-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                recursos: irq:35 memoria:d0400000-d0401fff
        *-usb:2
             descripción: USB controller
             producto: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1d
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             recursos: irq:16 memoria:d0738000-d07383ff
           *-usbhost
                producto: EHCI Host Controller
                fabricante: Linux 4.13.0-39-generic ehci_hcd
                id físico: 1
                información del bus: usb@2
                nombre lógico: usb2
                versión: 4.13
                capacidades: usb-2.00
                configuración: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   descripción: USB hub
                   producto: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   fabricante: Intel Corp.
                   id físico: 1
                   información del bus: usb@2:1
                   versión: 0.00
                   capacidades: usb-2.00
                   configuración: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             descripción: ISA bridge
             producto: QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1f
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             versión: 04
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             recursos: irq:0
        *-storage
             descripción: SATA controller
             producto: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1f.2
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             versión: 04
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 66MHz
             capacidades: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=ahci latency=0
             recursos: irq:31 ioport:2088(size=8) ioport:209c(size=4) ioport:2080(size=8) ioport:2098(size=4) ioport:2040(size=32) memoria:d0737000-d07377ff
     *-scsi
          id físico: 2
          nombre lógico: scsi0
          capacidades: emulated
        *-disk
             descripción: ATA Disk
             producto: Samsung SSD 850
             id físico: 0.0.0
             información del bus: scsi@0:0.0.0
             nombre lógico: /dev/sda
             versión: 2B6Q
             serie: S2RBNXAH284847Y
             tamaño: 465GiB (500GB)
             capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuración: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=e49c21ec
           *-volume
                descripción: partición EXT4
                fabricante: Linux
                id físico: 1
                información del bus: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                nombre lógico: /dev/sda1
                nombre lógico: /
                versión: 1.0
                serie: 77f9d50c-68b3-4514-8dbb-d7e592b40f0d
                tamaño: 465GiB
                capacidad: 465GiB
                capacidades: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuración: created=2017-06-14 21:42:43 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-04-29 17:24:50 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2018-04-29 17:24:51 state=mounted   *-battery
       producto: MI06048
       fabricante: 12-54
       id físico: 1
       ranura: Primary
       capacidad: 48840mWh
       configuración: voltage=11,1V
```